# perforce connect history of two different files

Tags: version-control, perforce

I have a problem, in a refactoring attempt I have copied files from one place to another and added them in my scm (perforce). When I was done and everything was working I deleted the old (moved) files.

Can I connect the file histories with each other? The best would be to se the "move" like it should have been done..

Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose your original file is `//source/old/file.c#5` and you moved it to `//source/new/file.c`, then deleted the old file in revision `//source/old/file.c#6`. You need to integrate from the old file to the new file, using the `-i` flag so Perforce will allow you to integrate between two files that it doesn't otherwise know of an integration history:

```
p4 integrate -i //source/old/file.c#5 //source/new/file.c
```

then resolve the files. Normally while integrating you'll want to accept a merged version of the file, but in this case you're mostly interested in letting Perforce know you already did the integration, so you can use `-ay` to "accept yours", discarding the old version of the file:

```
p4 resolve -ay //source/new/file.c
```

then submit the revision.

(Ideally you would have integrated first, then made any changes, and submitted everything, but this way the files will be linked in Perforce's integration history.)

Comment: Definitely learn to integrate first.  It makes many things easier, including tracking the history.